# table design for similar products

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design

Let's say I have N companies (N <= 15). Each company sells apples. I want to save apple properties in a database.

Company A describes following properties of their fruits: `type`, `field1`, `field2`,

Company B - `type`, `field1`, `field3`.

For company A and field `type`, there are 3 possible values: 1, 2 and 3. For company B they are 1, 2 and 4. I will have max 10 possible values for field `type` in total, around 20 possible fields in total and a looot of entries for apple properties. How should my tables look like?

Version 1:
Create an enum for `type` field, with all possible values merged (1,2,3,4). Create table `apples` with all possible fields (`type`, `field1`, `field2`, `field3`).

Version 2:
Create separate enums for `type` field for each company. Create separate tables for apple properties for each company.

Version 3: 
The same as version 2, but move common properties to next table.

Version 4:
Vesion 1 + table `type_config` saying which `type` values are allowed for each company. It would have `company_id` field (fk to some table), and a field with possible value / or fk to that value.

All of them seem bad to me. What would be the best solution in a real life?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use enums for this.  Use a proper reference table:

```
create table Properties (
    PropertyId serial primary key,
    Name varchar(255)
);
```

Then, create a table of properties for each company:

```
create table CompanyProperties (
     CompanyPropertyId serial primary key,
     CompanyId int references Companies(CompanyId),
     PropertyId int references Properties(Property),
     value ???
);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Trying to put Entity-Relations:
>
> > 1. There are n number of apple types in world
> > 2. Each type can have similar / different attributes
> > 3. One company can deal with 1..n different apple types
> > 4. There can 1..m companies.
> > 5. Transaction of apples by different companies
>
> You would need entities for;
>
> > 1. Company (For 4th item mentioned above)
> > 2. Different types of apple types in world (For 1st item)
> > 3. Types of apples with what attributes they can have (For 2nd item mentioned above)
> >
> >    > (a) It is better to have differentiation as mandatory attributes across types
> >    >          -- You can make these Not-null column
> >    >       (b) Non-mandatory attributes across types - Make them nullable columns
> > 4. Company selling what apples (For 3rd item mentioned above)
> > 5. Transaction table that can hold all types of apple transactions
> >
> >    - Company, Apple Type & other transaction items.